# Lavary Laravel-menu (submenu) not working

Tags: php, laravel, menu

I use the lavary laravel-menu but, my code not work.

```
protected function renderOutPut(){
    $menu = $this->getMenu();
    //dd($menu);
    $header = view(env('THEME','pink').'.partials.header')->render();
    $this->vars = Arr::add($this->vars,'header',$header);

    return view($this->template)->with($this->vars);
}

protected function getMenu(){
    $menu = $this->m_rep->get();
      //dd($menu);

    $mBuilder = Menu\Facade::make('MyNav',function ($m) use ($menu){
      foreach ($menu as $item){
          if ($item->parent == 0){
              $m->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);
          }else{
              if ($m->find($item->parent)){
                  $m->find($item->parent)->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);
              }
          }
      }
    });
    dd($mBuilder);
    return $mBuilder;
}
```

When I type after `else`  `dd($m->find($item->parent))` this get `null`. I can't find answer help me please if you know... In top  i type `use Lavary\Menu`

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer to my question.

After `else` need to add this code: `$m->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);`
Like this:

```
protected function getMenu(){
        $menu = $this->m_rep->get();
          dd($menu);

        $mBuilder = Menu\Facade::make('MyNav',function ($m) use ($menu){
          foreach ($menu as $item){
              if ($item->parent == 0){
                  $m->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);
              }else{
                  $m->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);
                  if ($m->find($item->parent)){
                      $m->find($item->parent)->add($item->title,$item->url_link)->id($item->id);
                  }
              }
          }
        });
        //dd($mBuilder);
        return $mBuilder;
    }
```

This work. **Because if you do not assign all elements on the object $m can 't find out what my object is looking for**